# Adding text to a bunch of files

Tags: bash, shell, find, cat

I needed to append some text to a bunch of files in a directory, so I thought I'd be clever and try something like this:

```
find . -name "*.txt" -exec cat source >> {} \;
```

Which did not work, of course, because the redirect gets picked up by the shell calling find, and not by the exec.

I ended up using BBEdit and a multi-file find/replace to do it, but I am sure there's some way to make find do this from the command line, but what?

Well, OK, I can think of one solution, but I don't like it: have exec spawn a shell for each result. That might work.

Comment: Is it just a directory without subdirectories? If so, you can do: `for file in /your/dir/*.txt; do cat source >> "$file"; done`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about :

```
find . -name "*.txt" -exec dd if=source of='{}' oflag=append conv=notrunc ';'
```

You should be able to use it with files with spaces and special characters.

Comment: I completely forgot that dd had the ability to append. This is very clever.

Answer (score 2):

You have at least two options:

```
find . -name "*.txt" -exec sh -c 'f={}; cat source >> $f' \;
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This executes the command invoking the `exec` function of `find`. Note it would be also convenient to use `-type f` just to match files.

Or you can use a simple `for` loop, that will loop through all the files matching the pattern `*.txt`:

```
for file in *.txt
do
    cat source >> "$file"
done
```

Comment: yeah, spawning a shell for each matched file seems like a bad idea if it's more than a few hundred files, but maybe that's just because I was 'raised' on a system with probably 16MB of RAM for 40 users.

Comment: Yes, true, in such case it is not a very good idea. However, I don't know how it will perform the `for file in *.txt` if it matches hundred of items -maybe you get the "too many arguments" error. Let us know how it works!

Comment: What if I create a file named "David's file.txt"

Comment: With bash "for file in *.txt" is not expanded. So you will never have "too many arguments".

Comment: @Vouze oh, you are right about the "too many arguments". Regarding the file named with some single quotes, in such case we should look for other ways (yours with `dd` could be one), but I think it is quite unlikely to happen and I prefer to leave the solution right how it is now. But thanks for pointing it and +1 for your approach.

Comment: The loop version will not descend into subdirectories; with `bash` 4, you can fix that by running `shopt -s globstar` and changing the loop to `for file in **/*.txt`.